# Selecting cells in collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:) makes the scroll to decelerate instantly

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, selection

**Context**:
I am building a collection viewing which when the user presses the header of a section it selects all the cells in that section. In addition, the section can have many items that will be fetched while scrolling. So, when a section is selected all the newly downloaded items needs to be shown and marked as selected.

Here's my problem. When the header is not selected, the scrolling is smooth even when items are fetched but when that header is selected, the scrolling stops it motion instantly. I really don't know what is causing this.

Also, I need to manually set the cell selection to true or false because the method `collectionView.selectItem(at:scrollPosition)` does not set the cell's isSelected property for an unknown reason.

Here's the code in the `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let sectionViewModel = sectionViewModels[indexPath.section]
        let cellViewModel = sectionViewModel.items[indexPath.row]
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellViewModel.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        (cell as? ViewModelConfigurable)?.configure(with: cellViewModel)
        
        if (cellViewModel as? Selectable)?.isSelected ?? false {
            cell.isSelected = true
            collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .left)
        } else {
            cell.isSelected = false
            collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        }
        
        return 
}
```

Does anybody ever faced the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you set allowsMultipleSelection and allowsSelection to true for this collectionView.selectItem(at:scrollPosition) to work?

Comment: Yes. Selections are working. The only problem is the choppy scroll. When the cell is selected, I only add a checkmark image in a corner. I also tried to rasterize it. No luck